# Como passar parâmetros para um Array em javascript?

Tags: javascript

Como eu poderia passar dinamicamente as informações para o `array` abaixo?

**Exemplo:** tenho uma listagem de 40 coordenadas em um arquivo de texto, por exemplo, ou em um banco `Access`, como passo essas coordenadas para a variável `locations` abaixo?

```
var locations = [
        {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
        {lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181},
        {lat: -33.727111, lng: 150.371124},
        {lat: -33.848588, lng: 151.209834},
        {lat: -33.851702, lng: 151.216968}
];
```

Comment: vc teria que mostrar o formato do arquivo de origem. Basicamente vc vai utilizar um get e um loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode passar as coordenadas para dentro da variável locations da seguinte forma:

```
locations.push(
   { lat: -30.851700, lng: 150.363100 }
);
```

### Atualizado

Através do recurso `push` você irá adicionar o item no final da variável locations (array). Vale ressaltar que você deve se certificar que está passando corretamento o objeto dentro da função `push`. Exemplo:

```
{
   lat: 10.00,
   lng: 20.00
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Caso o objeto já tenha sido criado você pode acessar usando o indíce do array e o a chave que você quer acessar.

Exemplo:

```
locations[0].lat = -51.00;
```

para acessar o primeiro elemento de *locations*.

Para adicionar novos elementos use o `push` e ele adicionara no final do seu array.

Exemplo:

```
locations.push({lat: -51.00, lng: 29.00});
```